# Select2 view doesn't change after changing ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I was working on creating a  element with select2 treatment. I created a angular directive for select2 dropdown. However, if I change the ng-model after the directive rendered, the view won’t get update.

Following is the link for a simple example in Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odiseo/zrchy7w0/5/

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<select ng-model="selectedOption" wb-select2 ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in optionList" select-width="300px"></select>
<button ng-click="changeModelOutside()">Click me</button>
```

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);
app.directive('wbSelect2', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
            'selectWidth': '@',
            'ngModel': '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //Setting default values for attribute params
        scope.selectWidth = scope.selectWidth || 200;
        element.select2({
            width: scope.selectWidth,
        });
    }
};
});



function Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.optionList = {
    'key1': 'Option 1',
        'key2': 'Option 2',
        'key3': 'Option 3',
        'key4': 'Option 4'
};

$scope.selectedOption = 'key3';
$scope.changeModelOutside = function () {
    $scope.selectedOption = 'key4';

};
}
```

By the way, the fix should **only** make changes **inside** the link function of directive, any fix **outside** the directive (I have tried using $(‘option’).select2().select2(‘val’,’1’)) will be only a work-around.

Have anyone found the same issue and have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zrchy7w0/6/

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" wb-select2 ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in optionList" select-width="350px" style="width:300px"></select>
    <button ng-click="changeModelOutside()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

---

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

app.directive('wbSelect2', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'selectWidth': '@',
            'ngModel': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //Setting default values for attribute params
            scope.selectWidth = scope.selectWidth || 200;
            element.select2({
                width: scope.selectWidth,
            });

            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue){
                element.select2().val(newValue);
            });
        }
    };
});



function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.optionList = {
        'key1': 'Option 1',
            'key2': 'Option 2',
            'key3': 'Option 3',
            'key4': 'Option 4'
    };

    $scope.selectedOption = 'key3';
    $scope.changeModelOutside = function () {
        $scope.selectedOption = 'key4';
    };
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null`!

Comment: Watching ngModel is a smart move, great job !